# implementing CAS authentication in java web application

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish, cas

I have a web application built with java JSP and servlets, using Glassfish3+ server. For now I am using form-based authentication for my admin console, however I want to switch to CAS authentication. Is this possible and how?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible. You need go over getting started section of CAS and download the library. Then modify your code as per CAS mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to CAS authentication by using a Java CAS client in your application :
- https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/CAS+Client+for+Java+3.1
- http://shiro.apache.org/cas.html
- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html
and a CAS server.
Best,
Jérôme